# Cannot get correct UIColor in rectangle

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics

All,

i have this piece of code :

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(0, 440, 320, 30));
```

and i call it like this :

```
_rectangeView = [[PopUpRectangle alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 538, 320, 30)];
```

but its BLACK!

anyone advice why this is ?

Comment: What is the value of `rect` in this. I suspect the rect you are colouring in is actually out of the rect of the view. bounds != frame and all that. NVM, added an answer.

Comment: Is `DrawRect:` ever getting called??? Place an `NSLog()` in there to see if it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your colouring rect like this...

```
CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 30));
```

Use 0, 0 as the origins not 0, 440.

That should work.

Inside drawRect you are dealing in the vector space of the view itself not its superview. So 0, 0 is the top left of your `rectangleView`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `_rectangeView` height is just 30 points but the context fill rect bounds `y` value is 440.0; exceeds the bounds of the view. Try changing the `y` value to 0 and you will see the color.